# Design issue on nested structure

Tags: c#, oop

I´m working on a project that deals with a huge amount of different kinds of objects retrieved from a database. For further considerations let´s suppose we have a much simpler structure as follows (for simplicity access-modifiers and such are omited):

```
class Outer {
    Mid mid;
    string someString;

    void createMid(string str) {
        // some work
        this.mid = new Mid(str);
    }
}

class Mid {
    Inner inner;
    string someOtherString;
}

class Inner {
    string innerString;
}

class Inner2 : Inner {
    // some custom behaviour for innerString
}
```

Now we create an instance of `Outer` that also instantiates its nested objects. Now we want to change some behaviour within the `Inner`-class by subclassing it (let´s say we want to set its `innerString`-property to some different value than in its base-implementation). My current approach for this is to subclass `Inner`. To create an instance of this derived class we also have to subclass `Mid`, whereby we also subclass `Outer`. Whilst creating this nested structure consists of many operations in the `Outer`-object we thus should also override most of our code only to instantiate `Inner2`-instance and thus also another instance of `Mid`.

I know that sounds like a huge design-flaw but I don´t come to any other solution for this kind of design than subclassing the whole structure and overriding the whole `createMid`-method just for this relative small sub-object. 
Is there any other approach for subclassing `Inner` without also subclassing all the others?

Comment: Use dependency injection, then you don't need to inherit everything. You pass the more derived `Inner` as the dependency for `Mid` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the **factory pattern**: Instead of instantiating `Inner` inside of `Mid` directly, call:

```
this.mid = InnerFactory.Create(/*parameters*/);
```

`InnerFactory` can then create `Inner` or `Inner2`, depending on the arguments.

What may be a little tricky is to provide the parameters so that the factory can decided which class to instantiate.

Comment: That sounds adequate to me.

Comment: After some time thinking I notice that I need a factory for every derived type thus doubling the total amount of participating classes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Your `Outer` class already has a `createMid()` method. Instead of creating factory classes you could also implement such `createXY()` methods for every class which realizes the factory method.