# Dynamically create instances of derived type

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

So let´s assume we have a Base-Assembly and a Custom-Assembly where every type within Base may or may not be overridden. So I have some code that creates a deep nested structure of some base-types. Now if I want to overwrite just some single type within this structure I would have to overwrite the whole structure to instantiate it. To ease this process I use a factory (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27012368/2528063)) that builds my inner-types.

```
public class MyFactory
{
    private Assembly _customAssembly = // get custom-assembly;
    private Type _actualType = null;
    private static MyFactory _instance = new MyFactory();

    private MyFactory()
    {
        // if we have custom assembly we search for classes that derive from our base-type
        if (this._customAssembly != null) this._actualType = this._customAssembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.BaseType == typeof(MyClass));
        // no derived type found so use the base-type
        if (this._actualType == null) this._actualType = typeof(MyClass);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an instance of either <see cref="MyClass"/> or an instance of a derived type of this class if there is any within the custom-assembly
    /// </summary>
    public static MyClass Create(string name) { return (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(MyFactory._instance._actualType, name); }
}
```

Now I can call the factory-method within my base-interface to create an inner-type. If this inner-type was derived within my custom-assembly I get an instance of that type instead of the base-type.

Now my question: As far as I know creating instances via reflection may take some time. Hence I´m creating such instances within a loop this may become a performance-relevant issue. I know that you may pimp up speed for invoking methods by using LINQ-Expressions (although I never did on my own). that point to the actual method. Thus we can directly invoke the method which may be much faster then using `MethodInfo.Invoke`. Is there any similar approach I can use to create new instances by declaring some kind of pointer to a constructor rather then a method?

Thanks for ya :)

Comment: Did you thinking about using DI container to instantiate this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to do this:

```
public class MyFactory<T> where T : MyBaseClass
{
    public static T Create(string name) { return new T{ Name = name }; }
}
```